# Get data of collapsible using a ID

Tags: javascript, html

I have set of 4 collapsible and each consists of functions to fetch the user input ,all the collapse works fine but on getting the status from device it shows correct status of only 1st collapsible.so i decided to set an ID to each collapsible but still unable to fetch the correct required output.

HTML Code:

```
<button id="cl1" type="collapsible" >PORT 1</button>
        <div class="content" >
            <br><br>
            <tr height=40>
                <td><style="text-align:middle">PORT1</td>
                <td width=40></td>
                <td><label id="sw1", class="switch">
                    <input type="checkbox">
                    <span class="slider"></span> 
                    </label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr height=40>
        <td width=40></td>
            <td>
            <form id="P1_pulsetime" oninput="">
                <br><br>
                10<input type="range" id="port1_pulseslider" min="10" max="120" value="20" onchange="pulserangevalueX.value=value"/>120
                <output id="pulserangevalueX">20</output>
                <br><br>
                <input type="button" onclick="Port1_pulsetime()" value="Port_1_pulse">
                <br><br>
            </form>
            </td>
            </tr>
        <tr height=40>
            <td width=40></td>
        <td>
            <label for="port1_timeday">PORT 1 SCHEDULE</label>
            <form id="port1_timeday" oninput="">
            <br><br>
                <label for="start_time">Start Time</label>
                <input name="start_time" id="start_time" type="time" min="00:00" max="24:00" required />
                <span class="hours"></span>
                <br><br>
                <label for="start_day">Day:</label>
                    <select name="start_day" id="start_day">
                        <option value="0">Everyday</option>
                        <option value="1">MON</option>
                        <option value="2">TUES</option>
                        <option value="3">WED</option>
                        <option value="4">THRUS</option>
                        <option value="5">FRI</option>
                        <option value="6">SAT</option>
                        <option value="0">SUN</option>
                    </select>

                    <br><br>
                    <label for="stop_time">Stop Time</label>
                    <input name="stop_time" id="stop_time" type="time" min="00:00" max="24:00" required />
                    <br><br>
                    <label for="session">session:</label>
                    <select name="session" id="session">
                        <option value="1">Morning</option>
                        <option value="2">evening</option>
                    </select>

        </td>
            <br><br>
            <input type="button" onclick="Port1_sch_On_off()" value="Port1_timeday">
            </form>
        </tr>
        </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        var coll_1 = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
        var i;

            for (i = 0; i < coll_1.length; i++) {
                coll_1[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
                        this.classList.toggle("active");
                        var content = this.nextElementSibling;
                    if (content.style.maxHeight){
                    content.style.maxHeight = null;
                    } else {
                    content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
                    } 
                });
            }
    });
```

Comment: You mention "collapsible" (type="collapsible")  as type not class & in jquery using name you trying to get object (document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");)

Comment: yes, I changed that.still my issue is same

Comment: add alert (alert(coll_1.length);) after var i; and add (alert(content.scrollHeight);) after  var content = this.nextElementSibling; & debug your code.. it was given me 1 & 409

Answer (score 0):

**You can use:**

`document.getElementById("nameOfID");`

**Get value:**

`document.getElementById("nameOfID").value;`

I hope it's helps ;)

Comment: tried that but ,it didn't worked since further it is taking collapsible length.

Comment: Is there some way to do it with If Else loop?